# How to redirect naked URL to www. URL in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, hosting, aws-amplify

For my website hosted in AWS Amplify,

I would like `example.com` to redirect to `www.example.com`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please post it here. Amplify redirect with Route 53 does not work for me